# istream to bool conversion: when is it available?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, type-conversion, clang

This simple code

```
bool foo(std::istringstream&stream, std::string&single, char del)
{ return std::getline(stream,single,del); }
```

compiles with gcc (4.8.2) but not with clang (3.4, using libc++), which complains that there is no viable conversion from `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >` to `bool`. However, when I wrap argument to the return statement in a `static_cast<bool>()`, clang is happy.

This confused me made me wonder whether the above code is well formed or not, i.e. whether gcc or clang is correct. According to [cpprefernce](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) `std::getline` returns a `std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >`, which is inherited from a `std::basic_ios` which has the type conversion `operator bool` (since C++11, before it was a type conversion to `void*`). Shouldn't this conversion operator get selected automatically? (for some reason, I'm more ready to accept that gcc is wrong than clang).

**Edit** I just figured out that apparently libc++ of llvm declares the conversion operator in question `explicit`, deeming it invalid for the implicit conversion. Is this in line with the standard?

Comment: `explicit operator bool()` means that the `basic_ios<>` object won't allow an implicit conversion to `bool`, the opposite of which gcc is allowing. I think clang is right here.

Comment: @0x499602D2 If you can back this up with a quote from the standard, I would accept a corresponding answer ...

Comment: @Walter why don't you download some random draft of the standard from the wg21 website, go to the chapter on input/output, find the definition of basic_ios, and see for yourself that there is `explicit` in front of the operator? It would take you less time than asking a question on SO... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool also says so.

Comment: @Marc Glisse : Because, by asking it as a question on StackOverflow, he was able to create an easily-accessible online reference answer to a problem that was keeping me from building a very large C++ codebase (ITK).  I am not a C++ programmer, and would certainly not even know where to look in the ANSI standard.  Thanks, Walter!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clang is correct. Since C++11, the conversion from `std::basic_ios` to `bool` is indeed required to be `explicit`.

C++11, `[ios.overview]`:

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the initialization that occurs in function return is the copy-initialization then the explicit conversion `operator bool` may not be applied implicitly. 
From the C++ Standard

> 2 A conversion function may be explicit (7.1.2), in which case it is
>   only considered as a user-defined conversion for direct-initialization
>   (8.5).

So GCC has a bug.

The operator may be applied implicitly when the direct-initialization is used or in special context as the context of  the if condition.